# Put data from MySQL to labels in a table in vb.net

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to put sum of each month in a label in the table from MySQL database but i dont know to make it in the label cz i have lbl1, lbl2, ... lbl12.
My code:

```
  connection.Open()

            query = "   SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table), MONTHNAME(Date_income_table) 
                        FROM bacci.income_table
                        where year(Date_income_table)='" & LblYear.Text & "'
                        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date_income_table);"
            Comand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            READER = Comand.ExecuteReader
            While READER.Read
                ChartIncomeYear.Series("Incomes").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("MONTHNAME(Date_income_table)"), READER.GetString("SUM(Amount_income_table)"))
            End While
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally

            connection.Dispose()
        End Try
```

[image: This is the table where i want the data to be]

this code will fill the chart but i also want to fill the labels with the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't have your label as lbl1, lbl2 and lbl3 etc. You should create them at run time. Try this code i a blank project. Adapt your code from this example. I like using list of objects but you can use an array too

```
Dim LabelList As List(Of Label)


Sub LoadSumLabel()
    LabelList = New List(Of Label)
    For x = 1 To 12
        Dim NewLabel As New Label
        With NewLabel
            .Name = DateAndTime.MonthName(x)
            .Text = "0"
            .AutoSize = True
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 10 + (LabelList.Count * NewLabel.Height)
        End With
        LabelList.Add(NewLabel)
        Me.Controls.Add(LabelList.Item(LabelList.Count - 1))
        AddHandler LabelList.Item(LabelList.Count - 1).Click, AddressOf Label_Click

        'you can create a panel and add you control to it the same way. So if you resize the form you can have the scroll bars if it doesnt fit
        'somepanel.controls(LabelList.Item(LabelList.Count - 1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim thisLabel As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    MsgBox(thisLabel.Name, vbOKOnly, "Result")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    LoadSumLabel()
End Sub

Sub RunQuery()
    connection.Open()

    query = "   SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table), MONTHNAME(Date_income_table) 
                    FROM bacci.income_table
                    where year(Date_income_table)='" & LblYear.Text & "'
                    GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date_income_table);"
    Comand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    READER = Comand.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
        ChartIncomeYear.Series("Incomes").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("MONTHNAME(Date_income_table)"), READER.GetString("SUM(Amount_income_table)"))
        LabelList.Find(Function(lb As Label) lb.Name = READER.GetString("MONTHNAME(Date_income_table)")).Text = READER.GetString("SUM(Amount_income_table)")


    End While
    connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally

    connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I change some stuff around

Comment: @sako no problems bud

Answer (score 1):

Name your labels like this lblJanuary, lblFebruary, lblMarch .... lblDecember. And then you can easily solve your problem using this code :

```
query = "   SELECT SUM(Amount_income_table) as Total, MONTHNAME(Date_income_table) 
            FROM bacci.income_table
            where year(Date_income_table)='" & LblYear.Text & "'
            GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date_income_table);"
Comand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
READER = Comand.ExecuteReader
While READER.Read
    ChartIncomeYear.Series("Incomes").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("MONTHNAME(Date_income_table)"), READER.GetString("SUM(Amount_income_table)"))
    Me.Controls("lbl" & READER.GetString("MONTHNAME(Date_income_table)")).Text = READER.GetString("Total")
End While
connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally

    connection.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: thank you i manage to get the same result by using if.. then..else statement but its long. this is better. @Md. Suman Kabir